# out of memory using c# clipboard

Tags: c#, c++, .net, mfc, clipboard

I have strange problem. My application written on C++/CLI includes MFC interface. My aim is get a text from a TextBox and do some calculation on the text with C# method. I decide pass the text via the clipboard. So I copy some small text from the TextBox to the clipboard and call the C# method that invokes `Clipboard.GetText()`. `System.OutOfMemoryException` occurres immediately. This exception is from the C# world not from C++. I'm confused of what is the origin of thisexception.

How could I solve this problem?

**C++**

```
bool onclick(CStringW text){
if (!OpenClipboard(hwnd)) return false;
    if (!EmptyClipboard())
    {
        CloseClipboard();
        return false;
    }

    bool result;
    CAutoDelGlobalAlloc hMem(::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, (text.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)));
    if (hMem)
    {
        CGlobalLock<WCHAR> lock(hMem);
        WCHAR* pText = lock;
        if (pText)
        {
            wcsncpy_s(pText, text.GetLength() + 1, text.GetString(), _TRUNCATE);
            pText[text.GetLength()] = L'\0';
            ::SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hMem);
            result = true;
        }
    }
    
    CloseClipboard();
    csharp_object.Process();
    return result;
}
```

**C# DLL**

```
public class CSharp_object{
    public void Process(){
         var text = Clipboard.GetText();
         
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what `CAutoDelGlobalAlloc` is, but you must not free the memory. From the [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata): "If SetClipboardData succeeds, the system owns the object identified by the hMem parameter."

Comment: There are a lot of easier ways to pass data between C# and C++, have you considered just passing a `System::String^`

Comment: Well from TextBox I get a CStringW text. So I should convert one to System::String^. It works. But sometimes the conversion calls AccessViolation. I think Clipboard using is more reliable way.

Comment: Realize that the clipboard is a system resource - not a passive buffer to be utilized by any app at any time.  Do you try to restore the previous contents of the clipboard (e.g. a movie clip, a spreadsheet workbook, et. al.?).  PC users utilize the clipboard system resource actively - they do not expect the contents to disappear or change without them actively doing so.

Comment: You're right. It should be done

Comment: "sometimes the conversion calls AccessViolation" - then your code has a bug. "Clipboard using is more reliable way" - I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

- The memory space you created with CAutoDelGlobalAlloc is cleared when you exit the method.
- The task of destroying the memory handle delivered to the clipboard is also delivered.
  Can you try as below? I hope it solves your problem.

```cpp
bool onclick(CStringW text){
    if (!OpenClipboard(hwnd)) return false;
    if (!EmptyClipboard())
    {
        CloseClipboard();
        return false;
    }

    int nLength = text.GetLength();
    int nSize = (nLength + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
    HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, nSize);
    if (NULL == hMem) {
        CloseClipboard();
        return false;
    }

    WCHAR *pwszData = (WCHAR*)GlobalLock(hMem);
    if (NULL == pwszData) {
        GlobalUnlock(hMem);
        CloseClipboard();
        return false;
    }

    if (nLength > 0) {
        memcpy_s((void*)pwszData, nSize, (const void*)text.GetString(), nSize);
    }
    else {
        pwszData[0] = L'\0';
    }

    if (FALSE == GlobalUnlock(hMem)) {
        GlobalFree(hMem);
        CloseClipboard();
        return false;
    }

    if (FALSE == SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hMem)) {
        GlobalFree(hMem);
        CloseClipboard();
        return false;
    }

    bool result = !!CloseClipboard();
    csharp_object.Process();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I solve the problem by removing CAutoDelGlobalAlloc. Your answer looks interesting. can you explain what a code means where twice "!" ? `bool result = !!CloseClipboard();`

Comment: Vitaly: I used it for conversion from "BOOL" to "bool". Same as (TRUE == CloseClipboard())